# Где правильно делать проверки на undefined

Tags: typescript, angular

Есть метод

```
product$!: Observable<Product>;

  getProduct(): void {
    this.product$ = this.route.params
      .pipe( switchMap( params => {
        return this.productServ.getById(params['id'])
      }))
  }
```

которая возвращает, объект типа

```
export interface Product {
  type?: string
  id?: string
  title?: string
  date?: Date | undefined;
}
```

и шаблон, который отображает свойства этого объекта

```
<div *ngIf="product$ | async as product; else loading">
  <h2>{{ product.title}}</h2>
```

В результате вызова метода (getProduct) переменная this.product$ может быть undefined.
Поэтому IDEA выдает ошибку в этой строке шаблона

```
<h2>{{ product.title}}</h2>
```

Как правильно решается эта проблема

- в шаблоне добавить проверку *ngIf="product.title"
- или эту проблему надо решать в коде, тогда вопрос как это правильно сделать

Comment: Посмотрите вот этот пример `https://metanit.com/web/angular2/6.2.php`

Answer (score 0):

можешь добавить [проверку?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```
 <h2>{{ product?.title}}</h2>
```